# MySQL Select JOIN multiple Tables

Tags: php, mysql, select, join, union-all

I essentially have two groups of tables. 'props_' and 'avail_'. Each with approx. 4 tables which i have joined using UNION ALL.

I need to select the properties with the necessary location & sleeps which don't appear in the availability tables for specific date ranges.

```
property tables... 'props_01', 'props_02', 'props_03', 'props_04'
   id    code         location    sleeps
   1     7A06E91875   devon       2
   2     440ac2664c   cornwall    4
   5     0474d4882b   devon       2


availability tables... 'avail_01', 'avail_02', 'avail_03', 'avail_04'
   id    prop_code     date
   1     440ac2664c    20130208
   2     440ac2664c    20130209
   3     440ac2664c    20130210
   4     440ac2664c    20130211
   5     440ac2664c    20130212
```

These **availability tables contain all the booked dates**. So i wish to only select from the property tables where they don't have an availability record for the specified date range. This is how i was looking to do query it...

```
(avail.date != '20130209' AND avail.date != '20130210' AND avail.date != '20130211' AND avail.date != '20130212' AND avail.date != '20130213') OR (avail.date != '20130210' AND avail.date != '20130211' AND avail.date != '20130212' AND avail.date != '20130213' AND avail.date != '20130214')
```

I also need to apply filters to the property tables for the location and sleeps.

The query i have which does everything apart from including the availabity is below, this works fine, but i don't know **how best to modify it to also query the availability tables**...

```
SELECT prop.* FROM (SELECT * FROM `props_01` UNION ALL SELECT * FROM `props_02` UNION ALL SELECT * FROM `props_03` UNION ALL SELECT * FROM `props_04`) prop WHERE prop.location='Devon' AND prop.sleeps>='4' ORDER BY prop.sleeps ASC
```

Comment: Why groups of tables? Why not 1 table for properties and one for availability?

Comment: because im using different sources so want to have a separate table for each source, also same for the availability. I wanted to use separate tables for each source because my advanced search will allow people to choose the source, so i thought this would be quicker as then i can query only one table for each as the availability table for one group of properties has over 150k records

Comment: What i mean by the 'source' is that there will be an option to choose which prop table to query, BUT 99% of the time i will need to query all of the sources (prop tables)

Comment: This is a TERRIBLE idea. If adding a property to the database means changes to the structure and all related queries, the implication is that you are doing something very wrong!

Comment: It's better to have data in separate tables rather than, querying one MASSIVE table with close to 500k of records!! How is this terrible!? Explain...

Comment: I thought I did! And 500000 rows of properly indexed data is peanuts for MySQL

Comment: I think you miss understand!! prop_01 will contain all the properties from one provider NOT just one property...

Comment: It doesn't matter. What if you add another provider? You're going to create a separate table for them? That is just plain wrong. Apologies if this appears conceited. But you will thank me in the long run.

Comment: Surely it would be quicker and easier to manage if each provider had a separate properties table...? I could use one table for the availability (if it would help speed the query), but i felt it was better to have separate tables for each availability as i was under the impression it would have been easier to query...?

Comment: No. It will be quicker and easier to manage one table, not 20 - or 200 - or whatever. Also, I don't understand the availability bit either. Normally you'd want to store when properties are 'booked' rather than when they're 'available' - but I suppose it's conceivable that you wouldn't have access to that information.

Comment: Basically, i have different lists of properties from multiple providers and also have a feed of the availability for each. So when querying for availability i need too only select the properties which are available for the date specified, ELSE displaying all properties regardless of availability status. I will now look to use  ONE table for the availability and multiple tables for each provider as that will be easier to manage

Comment: I would expect to see one table for providers, one table for properties, and one table for availabilities - and link tables as required - but hey, whatever floats your boat.

Answer (score 0):

You want a left join if you're looking for a row that doesn't exist in another table.  See this for more information:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/left-join-optimization.html

Comment: Thanks but how would that work if i want to query multiple tables? I applied the UNION ALL to both sets of table but the query threw up an error

Answer (score 0):

**To Join 3 tables  : Table1 , Table2 , Table3**

SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id
  LEFT JOIN table3 ON table2.id=table3.id;